# How to Export a Table (Shape) as JPG from Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am able to export Charts as JPG files from Powerpoint, but haven't been able to do this with a table, which as far as I can tell is still a "Shape" which should be able to export.

This is a cleansed version of the code I use to export the Chart as JPG.

```
Const imgFilePath as String = "ChartImage.JPG"
Sub ExportChartJPG()
Dim cht as Variant  'this will hold the Chart/Shape object

Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1").Chart

On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgPath
On Error GoTo 0

cht.Export imgPath, "JPG"

End Sub
```

I figured this would be simple to modify, like:

```
Sub ExportChartJPG()
Dim cht as Variant  'this will hold the Chart/Shape object

Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table1").Table

On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgPath
On Error GoTo 0

cht.Export imgPath, "JPG"

End Sub
```

But this is throwing an error `13` Mismatch.

I have also tried dimensioning `cht` as a Shape instead of Variant, and setting `cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table1")`, also unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although KazJaw's solution works, it was a bit cumbersome (copying takes additional time to process, I was getting errors I think as a result of not "waiting" long enough for the copy to complete, clipboard issues? etc.)

http://www.tech-archive.net/pdf/Archive/Office/microsoft.public.office.developer.vba/2006-10/msg00046.pdf

I open the object browser, right-click, and show hidden methods, which now allows me to use the `Export` method on a `Shape`.

```
Sub ExportShapeJPG()
Dim cht as Variant  'this will hold the Chart/Shape object

Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Table1") '<-- removed .Table and only pass the Shape itself

'Likewise, for charts, omit the .Chart:
' Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart1") 


On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgPath
On Error GoTo 0

cht.Export imgPath, ppShapeFormatJPG  '<-- The export syntax is slightly different using ppShapeFormatJPG instead of "JPG"

End Sub
```

Comment: From briefly reading that PDF, I think there are some additional arguments I could pass to re-size the exported image, but for now, this is definitely the approach I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 3):

I have one quite weird idea. Look at the code where first part save a chart and second save table.

```
Sub ExportinChartAndTable()
Dim imgFilePath As String
    imgFilePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\chart"

Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
Dim shpChart As Chart
    Set shpChart = shp.Chart
'exporting chart
On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgFilePath
On Error GoTo 0
shpChart.Export imgFilePath & "chart.jpg", "JPG"

Stop
Dim chartPart As ChartData
    Set chartPart = shpChart.ChartData

imgFilePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\dataTable.jpg"

chartPart.Workbook.worksheets("arkusz1").Range("a1:c20").Copy
shpChart.Paste
shpChart.Shapes(1).Width = shp.Width
shpChart.Shapes(1).Height = shp.Height
On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgFilePath
On Error GoTo 0
shpChart.Export imgFilePath, "JPG"


End Sub
```

You have to come up with idea how to check the range of the table. I hoped that `CurrentRegion` would work but it's not. You could use the possibility to count the amount of rows and columns in the table (it is possible). Or maybe you have fixed range so it would be easy. One more thing, you have to adjust dimension when table is resized.

**EDIT due to David comment.** I keep the above solution in place as could be useful for others (please refer to comments below)

```
Sub SolutionSecond()

Dim whereTo As String
    whereTo = ActivePresentation.Path & "\table.jpg"
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)



Dim chrt As Shape
Set chrt = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddChart

shp.Copy

'required due to excel opening proces
    chrt.Select
    chrt.Chart.Paste

'set dimensions here
chrt.Chart.Export whereTo, "JPG"

    chrt.Delete
 End Sub
```

This one base on the same logic. Copy table into chart which (the only kind of Shape) could be exported.

Comment: The solution you provide is for Excel - I think I could most likely do this in Excel if I needed to, but my problem is in Powerpoint where the table is created as a Shape within the slide, so I can't use this.

Comment: ok, I thought you want to get data which makes the chart. It would than go this way...

Comment: Nope, there is no chart in this case, just a Table object on the PPT slide, not in an Excel workbook.  Part of the Application I am developing also creates charts inside PPT, and I have no problem exporting the chart as a JPG, but so far haven't found a way to export the table shape.

Comment: So see the second idea in the answer above

Comment: THanks KazJaw. That is a creative approach to this problem. It is not a perfect solution but it is working for now. I will see if I can't find a better way to approach it,  but if not I will accept your answer.

Comment: If you find please share with us. I would be curious to know it.

Comment: I found an answer @KazJaw. Will post shortly.